# Email settings for custom domain in Microsoft Azure

Tags: email, azure, dns, zoho

I want to setup a mailbox for my custom domain bought in Microsoft Azure. For this, I am configuring Zoho Mail to be my mail box for the custom domain. Now I am supposed to configure email delivery settings. Zoho says -

> You need to configure the MX records of your domain in the DNS hosting provider (DNS Manager) to start receiving email to the users and groups created. You change the email service provider of the domain, only after this critical step.

Where do I find the email server settings of a web app in Microsoft Azure? Does Microsoft Azure even support this kind of stuff? Please help, thank you.

Comment: from where you bought your domain?

Comment: I bought the domain in Microsoft Azure itself... I have a subscription and Azure provides the facility of buying a domain.... For info - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/custom-dns-web-site-buydomains-web-app/

Comment: Okay, do they provide an interface for DNS management?

Comment: Yeah! Found it just now... In DNS management, there is Records, Nameservers, Forwarding (Domain & Sub Domain), and In Advanced Features - Manage Templates, Export Zone File (Unix), Export Zone, File (Windows), Import Zone File, Host names ....... What now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might have figured this out by now but this might prove useful for someone else.

In azure navigate to your app service. In the Settings section select Custom Domains. Select your domain name and then click on the Advanced Management button. This should take you to Azure Domain Manager, where you can again select your domain name. Under the settings icon you can select Manage DNS and here's where you can add your CNAME and MX details.

Comment: I id exactly this but I have experienced that the MX record is not updated towards my email provider. Has is worked for you easily within lets say 48 hrs?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to add TXT verification for Zoho for DNS-zone:

1. Click `+Record set` button
2. Select `TXT` in `Type` drop-down list
3. Put `@` into "Name" field
4. Copy and paste your Zoho TXT verification value to "Value" field

Zoho verification value looks like this:
**zoho-verification=XXYYYYYYYY.zmverify.zoho.com**

Quote from [zoho.com/cpanel/verify](https://mail.zoho.com/cpanel/verify):

> You may have to wait for at least an hour for the changes to take effect in the DNS Servers. After an hour or two, log in to your Zoho Mail Control Panel and click Verify.

[image: add-new-record-set]
[image]

Comment: Can I ask why to put @ as a name? I used some random user friendly name that I could think of and then the rest was set correctly and it did not work. So does the name has any special meaning? Thanks for advice.

Comment: @JS_Diver Basically, @ refers to your root domain. Let's say you have my-domain.com. When you add MX record to your domain (let's say you put "random" in the name field), then MX record is created for a sub-domain `random.my-domain.com`. Probably, @ is a way to not associate your root domain with an "empty" string for a domain provider. So, once again, the "name" in azure is not a name in common sense. I think about it as a "sub-domain". Godaddy uses the "host" field for the same purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I changed it to @ and the records have been reflected almost immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Start from here. Read through the article

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-custom-domain-name/

You have to add a MX record from the DNS management section of Azure portal.

Comment: Yes I have seen this, this is for the cname and a name.... But it doesn't tell anything about the email settings...